# How do i format this bash command to get templating working

Tags: bash

I'm creating a variable containing the current time with:

```
export timestamp=`date +"%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3N"`
```

I then want to template this into a curl to elasticsearch:

```
curl -u user:password https://search-es-test-knbc6zq6ahefsgrkr3ettpkrpwa.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com/hyperblast/_doc -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "function": "test3562", "timestamp": "$(echo $timestamp)", "message": "tested", "level": "error" }'
```

im getting error "Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers"

Answer (score 1):

Bash does not substitute anything between the single quotes. You should use double quotes `"` for the part of the argument which should be evaluated (i.e. `$(echo $timestamp)`):

```sh
curl -u user:password https://search-es-test-knbc6zq6ahefsgrkr3ettpkrpwa.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com/hyperblast/_doc -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "function": "test3562", "timestamp": "'"$(echo $timestamp)"'", "message": "tested", "level": "error" }'
```

Note that this code does not escape characters for JSON string. It should not be a problem for your date format, still keep it in mind.

Comment: `$(echo $timestamp)` is unnecessarily complex (and can have weird parsing problems) -- just use `$timestamp` directly.